# C error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type again

Tags: c, lista

Buenas para todos, estoy atascado con este codigo... es algo parecido a un caso que se presento anteriormente pero al hacer las correcciones sugeridas en dicho post, sigo teniendo el mismo error... por favor si me podrian ayudar...

Tengo estas dos estructuras

```
struct platos_por_pedido{
    int id_pedido;
    int item_nro;
    int id_plato;
    char observacion[30];
    char cocinero[2];
    char hora_inicio[4];
    char hora_fin[4];
    char estado[2];
    struct platos_por_pedido * ptrSiguiente;
};

typedef struct platos_por_pedido Platos_por_Pedido;
typedef Platos_por_Pedido * ptrPlatos_por_Pedido;


struct lista_platos_por_pedido{
    ptrPlatos_por_Pedido ptrCabeza;
    struct lista_platos_por_pedido * ptrSiguiente;
};

typedef struct lista_platos_por_pedido Lista_Platos_por_Pedido;
typedef struct Lista_Platos_por_Pedido * ptrLista_Platos_por_Pedido;
```

Luego en una porcion de mi codigo creo un puntero a la estructura lista_platos_por_pedido

```
ptrLista_Platos_por_Pedido nodoNuevoLista;

nodoNuevoLista  = malloc(sizeof(Lista_Platos_por_Pedido));
```

Un poco mas adelante trato de inicializar los componentes

```
nodoNuevoLista->ptrCabeza = NULL;
nodoNuevoLista->ptrSiguiente = NULL;
```

Y me tira dicho error en la primera linea donde intento inicializar.

Esto ya me dejo en la lona.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas seguro que el error viene de los segmentos colocados? Porque no logre reproducirlo.

Este es el codigo que use:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct platos_por_pedido{
    int id_pedido;
    int item_nro;
    int id_plato;
    char observacion[30];
    char cocinero[2];
    char hora_inicio[4];
    char hora_fin[4];
    char estado[2];
    struct platos_por_pedido * ptrSiguiente;
};

typedef struct platos_por_pedido Platos_por_Pedido;
typedef Platos_por_Pedido * ptrPlatos_por_Pedido;



struct lista_platos_por_pedido{
    struct platos_por_pedido * ptrCabeza;
    struct lista_platos_por_pedido * ptrSiguiente;
};

typedef struct lista_platos_por_pedido Lista_Platos_por_Pedido;
typedef struct Lista_Platos_por_Pedido * ptrLista_Platos_por_Pedido;




int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    struct lista_platos_por_pedido * nodoNuevoLista;
    nodoNuevoLista  = malloc(sizeof(struct lista_platos_por_pedido));

    nodoNuevoLista->ptrCabeza = NULL;
    nodoNuevoLista->ptrSiguiente = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!, justamente despues de preguntar, probe solamente esas porciones de codigo y la unica diferencia entre lo tuyo y lo mio es que yo tengo incluido <stdio.h>.

Comment: al agregar <stdio.h> aparece el error.  Lo estoy probando en CodeBlocks 16.01

Comment: Ahora estoy viendo las diferencias!

Comment: Este no va... ptrLista_Platos_por_Pedido nodoNuevoLista; 
Este corre de uuuna. struct lista_platos_por_pedido * nodoNuevoLista;

Comment: Hermano querido... Va de una!.  Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda!.  Lo lamentable es que sigo sin entender la diferencia entre uno y el otro si en teoria son lo mismo.

Comment: Ya lo vi... este era el error 
`typedef **struct** Lista_Platos_por_Pedido * ptrLista_Platos_por_Pedido;`